# Write a program that finds the average of several floats. allow the user to specify how many values that will be entered. limit number count to 20

Tags: c++, helper

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string num[21];
    int amount_num;

    cout<< "How many numbers do you want? (max 20)\n";
    cin>> amount_num;

    if (amount_num<= 0 || amount_num >= 22)
    {
        cout << "Invalid size.  Ending.\n";
    }
    for (int counter =0; counter < amount_num; counter++)
    {
        cout<< "Enter vaule "<< counter<< ":"<< endl;
        cin>> num[counter];
    }

    for(int t= 0; t< amount_num; t++)
    {
        int total;
        int average;
        total = total + num[t];
        average= total/ t;
        cout<< "Average: "<< average<< endl;
    }
    for(int x=0; x< amount_num; x++)
    {
        cout<< "You entered:"<< endl;
        cout<< num[x]<< endl;
    }
}
```

An error keeps popping up when I try to add the total plus num[t].
It states: error no operator+ in total+ num[t].

Comment: Why do you have array of `string`?

Comment: cannot add int and strings together

Comment: I changed the string to float. I also changed the variable total to float. I am how having an issue to get the average. it is giving me three different answers

Comment: '    for(int t= 0; t< amount_num; t++)

        {


        float total;
        float average;
        total += num[t];
        average= total/ t;
        cout<< "Average: "<< average<< endl;
        }'

Comment: At least make the pretense that you aren't asking for help on your homework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several things:

1. You are using an array of `string`, you should use array of `float`.
2. If you want average of `float` then variable `total` should be
   `float` instead of `int`

Comment: I changed the string to float. I also changed the variable total to float. I am how having an issue to get the average. it is giving me three different answers.

Comment: What kind of three different answers?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to move

```
int total;
int average;
```

before your loop and

```
average= total/ t;
cout<< "Average: "<< average<< endl;
```

after the loop otherwise you will just keep redefining  you variables and that will just break your code. 
Also you should declare the variable `total` and `average` as 0. You compiler should already be warning you about this.

If you do that you will end up with a code looking like this:

```
int total = 0;
int average;

for(int t= 0; t< amount_num; t++)
{
    total = total + num[t];
}
average= total/ amount_num;
cout<< "Average: "<< average<< endl;
```

that should fix the problem you are having with it returning multiple results.